Could not find com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.180.0
I am trying to render panaroma image on my react-native application. Tried few packages, but most of the devs suggesting this  https://github.com/lightbasenl/react-native-panorama-view.
Since, I have made some changes on build.gradlew for the package. I couldn't able to build the app. Is there anyway to fix this issue
build.gradle (app)
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.22"
    }
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

subprojects { subproject ->
    if(project['name'] == 'lightbase_react-native-panorama-view'){
        project.configurations { compile { } }
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"


build.gradle (react-native-panorama-view)
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        // Matches recent template from React Native (0.59)
        // https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.59-stable/template/android/build.gradle#L16
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

def safeExtGet(prop, fallback) {
    rootProject.ext.has(prop) ? rootProject.ext.get(prop) : fallback
}

// Matches values in recent template from React Native (0.59)
// https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.59-stable/template/android/build.gradle#L5-L9
def DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION = 28
def DEFAULT_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = "28.0.3"
def DEFAULT_MIN_SDK_VERSION = 19
def DEFAULT_TARGET_SDK_VERSION = 28

android {
  compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion', DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION)
  buildToolsVersion safeExtGet('buildToolsVersion', DEFAULT_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION)

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion safeExtGet('minSdkVersion', DEFAULT_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
    targetSdkVersion safeExtGet('targetSdkVersion', DEFAULT_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        // Matches recent template from React Native (0.59)
        // https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.59-stable/template/android/build.gradle#L30
        url "$projectDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    // Panorama
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
    implementation 'com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.180.0'
    implementation 'com.google.vr:sdk-common:1.180.0'
    implementation 'com.google.vr:sdk-commonwidget:1.180.0'
    implementation 'com.google.vr:sdk-panowidget:1.180.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
}

def configureReactNativePom(def pom) {
    def packageJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(file('../package.json').text)

    pom.project {
        name packageJson.title
        artifactId packageJson.name
        version = packageJson.version
        group = "nl.lightbase"
        description packageJson.description
        url packageJson.repository.baseUrl

        licenses {
            license {
                name packageJson.license
                url packageJson.repository.baseUrl + '/blob/master/' + packageJson.licenseFilename
                distribution 'repo'
            }
        }

        developers {
            developer {
                id packageJson.author.username
                name packageJson.author.name
            }
        }
    }
}

afterEvaluate { project ->
    // some Gradle build hooks ref:
    // https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/gradle-beyond-the/9781449373801/ch03.html
    task androidJavadoc(type: Javadoc) {
        source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        classpath += files(android.bootClasspath)
        classpath += files(project.getConfigurations().getByName('compile').asList())
        include '**/*.java'
    }

    task androidJavadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadoc) {
        archiveClassifier  = 'javadoc'
        from androidJavadoc.destinationDir
    }

    task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        archiveClassifier  = 'sources'
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        include '**/*.java'
    }

    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        def name = variant.name.capitalize()
        def javaCompileTask = variant.javaCompileProvider.get()

        task "jar${name}"(type: Jar, dependsOn: javaCompileTask) {
            from javaCompileTask.destinationDir
        }
    }

    artifacts {
        archives androidSourcesJar
        archives androidJavadocJar
    }

    task installArchives(type: Upload) {
        configuration = configurations.archives
        repositories{
            mavenDeployer {
                repository url: "file://${projectDir}/../android/maven"
                configureReactNativePom pom
            }}
    }
}



Add jcenter() this line in Gradle file
//.....

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.22"
    }
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

//.....


allprojects {   
    repositories {      
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()    

        google()    
        jcenter()   
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }        
    }

Reason : Because they have removed it. Navigate to directory android/build.gradle line no 13 and 35 since jcenter is no more active, but it's reachable as a read-only repository.
Note : This https://github.com/lightbasenl/react-native-panorama-view library will no longer updated and now archived.

@Rooban added reason why need to add jcenter.
